# How to find the highest value of a specified group using Python

Tags: python

In the example below, how do I find out the highest price of 'mansion' ?

**Data Description**

> this is a csv dataset contains three columns:h_type,h_price,y_year.
> Under the first column h_type, there are two different types of house, (mansion and apartment). The row is a list of a transaction.

**Usage**

> I want to be able to implement a code so when an end user request the price via linebot, it will automatically provide information.
>
> since there are tow types of house(mension and apartment), instead of finding a highest price of the whole data, i would like to narrow down to a specified type.

```py
bond=pd.read_csv('/content/.., index_col='h_type')

if bond.loc['mansion']:      #<= how?,bad code here
  idMax = priceSr.idxmax()
  if  not isnan(idMax): 
    maxSr = df.loc[idMax]
    if most is None:
      most = maxSr.copy()
    else:
      if float(maxSr['h_price']) > float(most['h_price']):
        most = maxSr.copy()

most = most.to_frame().transpose()
print(most, '\n==========')
```

**This is the error message**

```
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
   1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**However, when i try this, it works**

```py
bond=pd.read_csv('/content/...,index_col='h_type')
a=bond.loc['mansion']
aMax=a.sort_values(['h_price'],ascending=False).head(1)
```

please give me the advise to modify the bad code up there!

thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby('h_type').h_price.max()` Can you try this?

Comment: thank you for reply, i have found a similar code of this, but it is strange that it did not give the highest value(i must overlooked something), and the even more strange one is, when i try the code i put on my post, it works, just that i have no idea how to narrow down to the specific group

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `min()` and `max()` have two different signatures that allow you to call them either with an iterable as their first argument or with two or more regular arguments. The signature that accepts a single iterable argument looks something like this:

```py
min(iterable, *[, default, key]) -> minimum_value
max(iterable, *[, default, key]) -> maximum_value
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i am new to python and coding. i try the code and make a search for a little bit, but still find it hard to implement it. however really appreciate for your advice